# Express app not connecting to MongoDB in production - not sure why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

My express/react app works fine in development but for some reason won't connect to my production database on Mlab. All the routes that require interaction with the DB return a 503, service unavailable.

e.g. I'm using passport oauth2.0 with Google for login - this is firing the callback with the code, but then hangs because my callback tries to interact with the DB. Any other routes that require fetching info from the DB not returning a 503. This is my first ever app so I'm new to all this and I haven't got a clue why it's not connecting. My mongo_uri is set up as a Heroku config var, alongside my google client id and secret for OAuth, and I've set up the server to use these keys in production.

Everything is working fine in development, including authentication. I'm stuck on this one, haven't a clue why it won't connect and the Heroku logs don't help either. Please help!

Auth routes:

```
    app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

  app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/cabinet');
    });
```

Auth strategy setup:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Creates an instance of our user class (DB collection).
const User = mongoose.model('users');

// Sets a token for passport to pass as a cookie to the browser
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

// Takes the incoming token from the cookie and finds the associated user.
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});


// Set up the google strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: keys.googleClientID,
  clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
  callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
  proxy: true
},
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

    if (existingUser) {
      // We already have a record with the given profile ID
      done(null, existingUser);
    } else {
      // We don't have a user record with this ID, make a new record.
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(null, user);
    }
  }
));
```

Prod keys setup:

```
// Production keys
module.exports = {
  googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY
};
```

Production keys logic:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // we are in production - return the prod set of keys
  module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
  // we are in development - return the dev set of keys
  module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

I've also double checked that the mongoURI is correct and that my mlab user credentials for the prod DB are correct on Heroku, which they are.

Comment: Are both environments running on the same machine? If the response is "no" the next questions would be: are you sure that mongod is running in the production machine? And can you connect to mongo via shell?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm a noob so I'm not totally sure what you're asking lol! I've got node on my machine and installed express etc to create my server. Then used create-react-app to build my front end. I then deployed the app to Heroku using git and the Heroku CLI. I added a postbuild script to build the app on Heroku's server. I'm using mLab as my MongoDB so I didn't think I needed Mongo installed on any machine? I've not tried connecting via shell yet.